# Magento 2.1.2 showing error while installing

Tags: magento2

While I am trying to install Magento-CE-2.1.2 directly (not by composer) below error is showing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Magento 2.1.2 without the composer. Use the composer to reinstall the Magento 2.1.2.